# Swift: How to access the cells within a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

I currently have UITableView that has one UITableViewCell within it. Within my code I created a button over this cell. When that button is pressed, the cells within it expand.

How would I go about making something expand when one of those cells are selected? Would I need to put a UITableView within the cell?

Comment: Your question is unclear. I think what you mean is you have a table view with 1 cell in it, and a button in that cell. When the user taps the button, the cell's section expands -- i.e. you add more cells to that section dynamically. In iOS, this kind of UI is typically performed with a navigation controller. You tap the cell, and it pushes another table view controller, or a detail controller etc. But please clarify a bit.

Comment: Indeed! When that initial cell is clicked, say 6 cells then expand. At that point, I'm trying to then have another cell push forward. I believe it has something to do with (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath      but I'm not whether I would need to add anything to the storyboard or not..

Comment: An example would be the project titled: "ExpandableTableViewSections" on https://github.com/quantumarun/Demos     After selecting one of the inner cells (such as Tomato), how would you create another cell that expands below that cell that says something else (for example a textfield that allows you say how many tomatoes).

Comment: One option would be to put a UITableView inside each cell. See this [post](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/) which uses a collectionView in a table cell, the approach would be similar. You could also insert a new "quantity" row below the tapped row in the same section.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do if I needed to bang something out in a hurry. Let each vegetable occupy its own table section, then expand or contract the section when the user toggles:

```
// We need some kind of data model.
class Vegetable {
    init(name: String, facts: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.facts = facts
    }
    let name: String
    let facts: [String]
    var isShown: Bool = false   // This flag gets toggled, which is why I've defined it as a class.
}

// And a table view controller configured for dynamic (not static!) cells. Create this in a storyboard, and change the UITableViewControllers class to VeggieTable.
class VeggieTable: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        veggieData = [Vegetable(name: "Tomato", facts: ["Number: 15", "Red Colored"]),
                      Vegetable(name: "Lettuce", facts: ["Good with peanut butter", "Green", "Crunchy snack"])] // etc.
    }

    var veggieData: [Vegetable]!

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return veggieData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let veg = veggieData[section]
        return veg.isShown ? veg.facts.count + 1 : 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let veg = veggieData[indexPath.section]

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel?.text = veg.name
        default:
            cell.textLabel?.text = veg.facts[indexPath.row - 1]
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let veg = veggieData[indexPath.section]
        // Toggle the is shown flag:
        veg.isShown = !veg.isShown
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        // TODO: replace reloadData() with sophisticated animation.
        //        tableView.beginUpdates()
        //        tableView.insertRows() / deleteRows() etc etc.
        //        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Eventually you'd add table animations to make the rows appearing look smooth etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this. Did you happen to create a storyboard for this bit of code? If possible, could you attach a picture of that? Did you add another cell in the UITableView (which would correspond with veg)?

Comment: This is standard boilerplate. It took me about 20 minutes to write and proofread, and it's a good exercise to keep my brain sharp. It's a good example for how it all comes together. Your task is to create a storyboard (or roll your own `loadView()` method that creates the table view programmatically) that instantiates the `VeggieTable` view controller.

There are many really great tutorials out there that explain how to do this. Good luck.